# Simple meaning to Center of a group

Tags: group-theory

Recently I was learning Center of groups and on referencing the group table, I observed is that all the rows that are also present as columns are the centers of any group. 
So, I made a small program to check it for various groups and found somewhat consistent answers. I wrote a small blog on it but I have a fear in my heart if it is only true or not and my post might send some wrong information to other person.

The way I made program was to find similar rows and columns instead of calculating $xg=gx$ as per definition. Is it perfectly fine to let it be so?

Comment: To state that a little more carefully: $g$ is in the center iff the $g$ column equals the $g$ row in the table (if elements are listed in the same order, of course). And I guess you are talking about finite groups. If $A$ is the square matrix representing your group table, then what you are looking for is the null columns (or rows, if you prefer, it does not change anything) of the symmetric matrix $A-A^t$.

Comment: yes I observed this too...their position is also same !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. For some element $g \in G$, the $g$th row (let's write this short for the row corresponding to $g$) consists of the elements $gx$ for $x \in G$ in some particular order, the $g$th column of the elements $xg$, $x \in G$ (same order on the $x$s). If row and column are equal elementwise, this means $gx = xg$ for all $x \in G$, that is exactly true if $g \in Z(G)$.

Comment: ok thanks for reassurance...!